# How to use contact_ws if the value is null

Tags: php, mysql

This is my current code:

```
SELECT id, name, concat_ws(',', tag1, nullif(tag2, ''), nullif(tag3, '')) FROM TABLE
```

And

```
echo '  '.$result[$x]['GROUP_CONCAT(tag1)'].' '.$result[$x]['GROUP_CONCAT(tag2)'].'  ';

Error: Notice: Undefined index: GROUP_CONCAT(tag1)
```

What s wrong in my code?

Comment: You need to alias the values, for example: `..., concat_ws(',', tag1, nullif(tag2, '') AS concat1, ...`

Comment: Like this? `concat_ws(',', genres1, nullif(genres2, '') AS concat1,concat2)`

If yes, then it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
SELECT id, name, concat_ws(' , ', tag1, nullif(tag2, ''), nullif(tag3, '')) as data FROM TABLE
```

Then print it as

```
echo $result[$x]['data'];
```

It will give out put as

```
tag1 , tag2 , tag3
```

I thing it will help you.